# can not set the camera viewpoint?

Tags: python, camera

I want to use python to set the camera viewpoint but failed to do so, here is my code to render the model through python

```
import sys 
import os
import bpy 
import math 
import datetime

if __name__=="__main__":

    configureBlender()
    setCameraPosition([0.49123,-2.22974,6.74501],[123.942,0.578,0.1])
    run(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/test')

def configureBlender():
    # rendering constants
    RENDER_RES_X = 640
    RENDER_RES_Y = 480
    FRAME_NO = 1
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = FRAME_NO
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = RENDER_RES_X
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = RENDER_RES_Y
    bpy.context.scene.render.use_border = False

def run(output_dir):        
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_dir
    nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
    links = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links
    nodes['File Output'].base_path = output_dir
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

def setCameraPosition(location, rotation):
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].location = location
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].rotation_euler = [math.radians(rotation[0]), math.radians(rotation[1]), math.radians(rotation[2]) ]
```

I don't know what is wrong with code or maybe model(anywhere to upload the model, it is 5mb)

**update**

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    print(obj.name)
```

it prints out only one Camera object, i guess if there is only one camera, this camera must be the active camera.

Another wield thing is i changed the camera position and saved the model but it is still rendering with the previous viewpoint. so I guess maybe the code is fine but something wrong with the model.

here is my model link

[image]

Comment: You can. What's your question about? Rendering, setting up the camera in your scene? Compositor nodes? Command line? Don't get it... please add more context.

Comment: Rendering through the code is fine however no matter how I set the parameters in the  camera viewpoint, the rendered picture still keeps the same camera viewpoint set previously in the model.

Comment: You really want to set `context.scene.camera` location and rotation.  There may or may not be a camera in the file named "Camera" but it is not always going to be the scene's active camera.

Comment: i print out all the objects, and it shows the Camera object with exact the name

Comment: @batFINGER I have uploaded the model

Comment: I think @Doyousketch2 has nailed the issue with his edit, regarding code order.   My camera comment is regarding change the name of cam, or use diff camera for scene and this script fails.  Suggest passing scene to all these methods  eg `def configurescene(scene, ..):`  with `scene.some_setting = some_value` instead of `bpy.context.scene.some....`

Answer (score -1):

Is this the entire script?  It looks like you forgot to import required modules.

```
import os  
import math
```

**Edit:**

Er, well, I think Blender automatically does *import math as **
so you'd remove the preceding **math.** from radians.

I believe you'd still need to *import os*, unless I'm mistaken about that point.

**Edit**  You have to define functions before you can run them in Python.  Don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish with node tree in your run function, so I chopped that out for now, but this script at least runs.

```
import bpy, os
from math import *

# rendering constants
RENDER_RES_X = 640
RENDER_RES_Y = 480
FRAME_NO = 1

def configureBlender():
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = FRAME_NO
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = RENDER_RES_X
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = RENDER_RES_Y
    bpy.context.scene.render.use_border = False

def run(output_dir):
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_dir
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

def setCameraPosition(location, rotation):
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].location = location
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].rotation_euler = [radians(rotation[0]), radians(rotation[1]), radians(rotation[2]) ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configureBlender()
    setCameraPosition([0.49123,-2.22974,6.74501],[123.942,0.578,0.1])
    run(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/test')
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue. (there is no `import bpy` either)  Suggest asking "Is this the entire... " in a comment.

Comment: bpy is automatic, the way math was used was wrong.

Comment: You can `import math` and `math.radians()` or `from math import *` and `radians()`.   If only using radians recommend `from math import radians`. The fix is your Edit, re where the `if __name__ ==...` was defined.

Comment: You can import it a number of ways.  Blender by default uses from math import *  My point was: math didn't appear to be imported at all.

Comment: My point. Wouldn't bother answering questions with you've forgotten to import a or b as it's a simple syntax error, and if it is the answer it shouldn't be a question in the first place Make it  comment first.   Blender doesn't by default `from math import *`. Try run this  one line script in editor `cos(0)`.   Math methods / props are available to the console and ui and driver namespaces, perhaps that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's used in the interactive console.  My answer still stands as a viable solution regardless how much you want to nit-pick about minor details.

Comment: Calling me a nit picker doesn't make "Er, well, I think Blender automatically does import math as *
so you'd remove the preceding math. from radians. " right.  Why not just edit it out.  I imagine most use the text editor to run scripts rather than paste them into interactive console.

Comment: I felt it was better to leave the original text as is, in case user824624 had already read that part.  I've actually put forth something that resembles a solution.  All you've done is complain about the formatting of my text.  Why don't-cha go troll someone else.